# Почему border:...; заполнятеся цветом не полностью?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.card__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__bg"></div>
</div>
```

Можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: Какой браузер и версия?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Chrome Версия 88.0.4324.104

Comment: Я сейчас на хроме 88, смотрю в сниппет и всё норм)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е дело в браузере? Интересно очень, этот же код посмотрел в codepen так пустота вообще с левой стороны

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на кодпен глянем, у меня тоже ничего примечательного)

Comment: https://codepen.io/tema21978/pen/BaQaVKN

Comment: все нормально вообще, скрин снял и в фотошопе увеличил - черная граница в 2 пикселя, все в норме, никаких артефактов нет

Comment: А в браузере зум 100%?

Comment: Была похожая ошибка (в хроме обычно такое, а в Firefox отображается нормально). Попробуй объединить стили из 2 классов, сработает?

Comment: В хроме нормально выглядит.